# How to configure an IP phone in a home network

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, telephony

I asked a question in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82973/how-to-configure-an-ip-phone-in-a-home-network?noredirect=1#comment149990_82973

my ISP gave me a number with default RJ11 analog phone. I don't know much about computer networks. my case is:

I want to buy an IP phone for my home, these phones are widely used in offices, I don't know if it can be adapted to my home network.

I guess these phones have better audio quality during calls.

IP phones can be connected to RJ11 or only mandatory to RJ45.

My Modem has these options disabled:

Application Layer Gateway

ICQTalk
Net2Phone
IRC7000
IRC8000
NetBios
RSVP
Kerb88
IKE
ICQ
Kerb1293
MSN

But these options are enabled by default

**FTP**

**TFTP**

**RTSP**

**H225**

**PPTP**

**SIP**

**IRC666x**

How is an IP phone, can you assign the analog phone number to the IP only by connecting to the modem?

Or do I have to do any configuration on my modem or buy a switch?

If so, would I choose to use Asterisk.

I also understand that phones require a DNS server to be able to communicate with the outside world, just like web pages do.

Yes, I bought an IP phone, should I set up a DNS server, or can my modem's default DNS be used?

If a DNS server should be configured, can DNSmasq be used, is it the same as that used in web pages hosted on Linux?

I also have access to the configuration of

port triggers
Virtual servers
I know a little about some of the concepts mentioned, but the truth is that I have never configured a telephone network.

If this is not the right place to ask, can you recommend a stackoverflow forum where you can help me.

Comment: These generally connect to Ethernet. Did you ask your ISP for assistance for your particular phone and situation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because User has no experience, many questions, and needs the ISP or a local contractor to help set it up.

Comment: No, I have not asked my ISP for help. John

Comment: And precisely I ask why I am learning. Because in my education in systems I only have theoretical knowledge, not practical.

The idea is that someone recommends me where I can find information on how to install this type of network.

Comment: I don't see why having a contractor. In my school I only got to see network theory. But I have never practiced. That's where the question came from.

Comment: And if given, how could I explain my case to a contractor. for him to share some of his knowledge

Comment: Because I'm sure he helped me without a doubt, but I won't say how he did it, at least that's my opinion.

Comment: You are supposed to connect the phone to your network via an rj45. The phone then grabs an IP address from the DHCP server. Then you connect to that IP address using a browser, where you will configure it. If your isp gave you an analogue phone, then perhaps they expect you to connect it to the analogue port on your router. Quite a few have them.. Perhaps though you did not explain your requirements properly to them.

Comment: Did the phone come with a guide? Which phone? Is it compatible with the service you have purchased? IP phones don't really have better audio quality. I would guess that the service and/or device has a guide specific to them, and you should start there. I pay for phone from my ISP and don't need an IP phone for that. The modem had the rj11 port for the phone service. There are IP phones that will connect over your internet to an external service too, no features needed on your modem or router. I'm guessing that you're looking in the wrong place, and it may be much simpler than you think.